# Background doesn't resize in responsive tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm busing `tailwindcss` for my css. So for this I defined the image inside the tailwind config. Then I applied a `cover` on it but the image doesn't scale when I change the size of the screen. I thought by adding `max-w-full min-h-full` would fixe the problem but nothing.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { CountdownEvent } from './CountdownEvent'
import { CarouselSaf } from './CarouselSaf'
import { Navbar } from './Navbar'

export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <section className="h-screen">
            <div className="bg-safthon bg-no-repeat bg-cover max-w-full min-h-full">
                <Navbar />
                <div className="flex h-screen items-center">
                    <CountdownEvent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you host some visual, repro ? https://play.tailwindcss.com/ [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to keep it simple. Check this [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/iHgKYI8rAb).

```
<div class="min-h-screen max-h-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat" 
style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/odM92ap8_c0/maxresdefault.jpg')">
</div>
```

Comment: yes I was missing the max-h-screen, thank you.